# Parsing/Rescuing corrupted IDA database

Tags: ida, binary-analysis, file-format, struct, hex

I'm reversing an application with IDA.
My VM crashed and left the IDA database in a corrupted unpacked state.

The next time I tried to load it back, IDA gave me the following error message: `The input database is corrupted: CRC32 mistmatch. Continue?` a few times, then it quit with the error `bTree error: index file is bad`. Google-ing these error messages gave no useful results, which is unusual.

I'ld like restore the database, or at least extract the data somehow.

I've already tried the following:

- Zynamics bindiff (couldn't open the IDB, said it's probably opened in another IDA instance, which I guess Is a result of the corrupted data)
- Manual hex diff - I just can't interpret the output.

At this point I'm thinking of somehow **parsing the IDB** and then diffing that output manually.

**So, how can I parse/extract data from IDB files?**

[Related.](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3452/how-do-you-manage-backup-your-ida-database)

Comment: In such a case the first thing I would do is: cancel. After that I'd take a backup of the packed and the unpacked IDB and then proceed with either of the choices IDA gives and then backtrack and use the other choice if the former doesn't work. If your VM crashes the state of the DB is likely in an inconsistent state, so the best bet is to contact `support@hex-rays.com`. Otherwise you can use the SDK and the IDA book to figure out the details of the IDB format and extract what details you can salvage.

Comment: @0xC0000022L Is there such public tool to parse IDBs you know of?

Comment: I'm not aware of one, no.

Comment: http://www.openrce.org/forums/posts/917

Comment: @VitalyOsipov: I find myself in this situation every now and then. And while it makes sense to ask Hex-Rays support it makes equally sense to inquire about a public key. For example it could be that the IDB contains sensitive data that must not get to any third party under any circumstances. So I think regardless of the background it's a valid and valuable questions. I for one hope to see an answer pointing to such publicly available tool. Even if it may only sate my appetite for curiosity about the IDB format without digging into `netnode.hpp` ;)

Comment: If someone gives an answer pointing to an open source tool that is publicly available, I'll reward that with 150 extra reputation points on top of Dominik's bounty.

Comment: The best person to answer this is Ilfak G. himself.

Comment: Ilfak always responds really rapidly. Contact him, he'll probably ask you for your idb file and (when something like this happened to me) you'll get the patch in a number of days. Also, _always_ keep a backup.

Comment: @Stolas This is a twisted situation, because I'm bound by a contract, I can't give the said IDB out to anybody.

Comment: @DominikAntal Still, I'd recommend to contact him and explain the situation. But lets continue in the chat on this subject. As this is not the correct location to talk about this.

Comment: I don't know about the close reasons (and requirements) here, but if OP doesn't have this problem anymore (it's been a year), should it be closed?

Comment: I did not find a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I published some tools on github which can do just that: https://github.com/nlitsme/pyidbutil and https://github.com/nlitsme/idbutil.
The first is written in python, the second in C++, both have similar functionality.

`pyidbutil` provides the most low level recovery options: using `--pagedump` you can dump each page in the file without the need of an intact logical file structure.

Comment: The hero we needed has arrived! :)

Comment: Worth noting that there is also a new tool/framework to work with IDB files: https://github.com/williballenthin/python-idb

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, I cannot provide answer what to do when your database is already corrupted. That's the nature of proprietary binary databases: if you're hosed, you've got to keep all the pieces.

But I may suggest that you should foresee and be prepared to IDA database corruption, which is imminent and happens sooner or later to almost everyone. So:

1. Prefer using unpacked database (less bugs to trigger in IDA).
2. Make backup of binary database files early and often.
3. Save your database as an IDC file early and often (File -> Produce File -> Dump database to IDC file).

Give step 3 a special attention - an IDC file is your ticket out of IDA walled garden. It is known that it doesn't contain all the information IDA stores in the database, but it has most important, and it is a text file which you can re-import into IDA to restart analysis with just an executable file, or process with a simple script to filter out needed data, etc.

Overall, the problem of database corruption can be solved only with an open tool which uses database in open format. As a shameless plug, I work on interactive disassembler which stores database in a simple text format - [ScratchABit](https://github.com/pfalcon/ScratchABit). Sooner or later, IDC import script will be written for it.

Answer (score 2):

In my instance the error was "**Read error: read past end of file (file position 0x0, wanted 0x20X bytes, read 0x0**".

After trying different things for a while, I realised the .id2, .nam and the .til unpacked database files were all having a size of 0KB. Opening the same executable file as a new database, the associated .id2, .nam and .til files had definite sizes.

What I did was to **replace the .til file of the corrupted database with the .til file of the new database**. The database opened and breakpoints were intact.

The only issue was that the names window became empty. However looking through the database, I realised the names I had entered manually were still there but were in greyed text. At this stage though, **it would not be difficult to recover the names using a script as the names and their addresses are part of the database text**.