# How do you manage/backup your IDA database?

Tags: ida

Recently I lost an important IDA database. Up until now, I manually made a copy of my work IDB every day, but that's obviously not a good backup technique. I was wondering how do you manage/backup your IDB. Like make a copy of the current IDB every minute or something like that.

Comment: AFAIK you'd have to write a plugin for this, although there is a crude (IMO) autosave feature (`AUTOSAVE` in `cfg/idagui.cfg`) to make this a meaningful autosave. Simply using an external tool without previously writing the IDB will likely result in a similar situation you're encountering with the IDB from the crashed VM.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The recently added [database snapshot feature](http://www.hexblog.com/?p=415) allows you to set up periodical snapshots of your database.

[image: IDA Database snapshot manager]

Comment: how (if at all) is this related to the feature controlled by the `AUTOSAVE` setting in `idagui.cfg`? Also, is the hierarchical snapshot feature that Ero suggested implemented? Starting with which version of IDA?

Comment: `AUTOSAVE` only flushes in-memory changes to disk, it does not create a complete database copy. Hierarchical snapshots were in the initial release (6.2).